# Can MIL-PRF-5606H hydraulic fluid be used in place of MIL-PRF-5606?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, braking

Can MIL-PRF-5606H hydraulic fluid be used in place of MIL-PRF-5606?  My airplane is a 1966 Piper Cherokee 6.

Comment: Hello David Allen, welcome to aviation.stackexchange!

Comment: Kind of related: [What is the difference between MIL-H-5606 and MIL-PRF-5606 hydraulic fluid?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45721/what-is-the-difference-between-mil-h-5606-and-mil-prf-5606-hydraulic-fluid)